# $this->Form->postLink redirect to '#' cakephp 3.4

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm actually developping an application using the "AdminLTE" template.

The "postLink" worked normally for me before adding the "Authentification" stuffs, since that all the postLinks are redirecting me to "../currentpage#", notice that "currentpage" is the name of my current page & the "#" is added to the link instead of redirecting me to the wanted action. Here is my code:

index.ctp(Departments)

```
  <?= $this->Form->postLink(" ", ['controller' => 'Departments', 'action' => 'delete',$department->id ],['confirm'=> __('Are you sure you want to delete # {0}?', $department->name),'class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-flat fa fa-trash','title'=>__('Delete')],array('escape' => false)) ?>
```

DepartmentsController.php

```
  public function delete($id = null)
{

    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    echo "Ok";
    $department = $this->Departments->get($id);
    if ($this->Departments->delete($department)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The department has been deleted.'));
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The department could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller
{


    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');

        $this->loadComponent('Auth',[
            'logoutRedirect' => [
                'controller' => 'Pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ]
        ]);
    }

    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }

        $this->viewBuilder()->theme('AdminLTE');
        $this->set('theme', Configure::read('Theme'));

        parent::beforeFilter($event);

        $this->Auth->allow();
    }
}
```

Finally, UsersController.php:

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    public function delete($id = null)
    {
        $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        if ($this->Users->delete($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }

        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actionally I found the error in another file, the thing I did, is that I duplicate the main content of the template & thiscontent was not displayed, so a confusion was created, such as the computer didn't know the source of the click(Postlink/Postlink Duplicated).

../Plugins/AdminLTE/src/template/layout/default.ctp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title><?php echo isset($theme['title']) ? $theme['title'] : 'HONOR Delivery System'; ?></title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('AdminLTE./bootstrap/css/bootstrap'); ?>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webroot/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('AdminLTE.AdminLTE.min'); ?>
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
        folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('AdminLTE.skins/skin-'.(isset($theme['skin']) ? $theme['skin'] : 'blue').'.min'); ?>

    <?php echo $this->fetch('css'); ?>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-<?php echo isset($theme['skin']) ? $theme['skin'] : 'blue'; ?> sidebar-mini">
<!-- Site wrapper -->

<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="main-header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="<?php echo $this->Url->build('/'); ?>" class="logo">
            <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
            <span class="logo-mini"> <?php echo ("HDS") ?> </span>
            <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
            <span class="logo-lg"> <?php echo ("HONOR<strong>DSystem</strong>") ?> </span>
        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <?php echo $this->element('nav-top') ?>
    </header>

    <!-- Left side column. contains the sidebar -->
    <?php echo $this->element('aside-main-sidebar'); ?>

    <!-- =============================================== -->

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">

        <?php echo $this->Flash->render(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Flash->render('auth'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

    <div class="footer" style="background-color: #222d32;" >
        <?php echo $this->element('footer'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->element('modalOpinions') ?>

    <!-- Control Sidebar -->
    <?php echo $this->element('aside-control-sidebar'); ?>

    <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
    <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
        immediately after the control sidebar -->
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg" style="  background-color: #222d32;"></div>
</div>

<!-- ./wrapper -->
<div class="loginV"> <!-- le Login en dehors de la template(wrapper) -->
    <?php echo $this->Flash->render(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Flash->render('auth'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
</div>

<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min'); ?>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./bootstrap/js/bootstrap'); ?>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min'); ?>
<!-- FastClick -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./plugins/fastclick/fastclick'); ?>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE.AdminLTE.min'); ?>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<?php echo $this->fetch('script'); ?>

<?php echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".navbar .menu").slimscroll({
            height: "200px",
            alwaysVisible: false,
            size: "3px"
        }).css("width", "100%");

        var a = $('a[href="<?php echo $this->request->webroot . $this->request->url ?>"]');
        if (!a.parent().hasClass('treeview')) {
            a.parent().addClass('active').parents('.treeview').addClass('active');
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The Original main content:

```
        <?php echo $this->Flash->render(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Flash->render('auth'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

Duplicated:

```
<!-- ./wrapper -->
<div class="loginV"> <!-- le Login en dehors de la template(wrapper) -->
    <?php echo $this->Flash->render(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Flash->render('auth'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
</div>
```

The Solution: DELETE THE DUPLICATED CONTENT

Finally you'll have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title><?php echo isset($theme['title']) ? $theme['title'] : 'HONOR Delivery System'; ?></title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('AdminLTE./bootstrap/css/bootstrap'); ?>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webroot/favicon.ico">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('AdminLTE.AdminLTE.min'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('antiLogin'); ?>
    <!-- AdminLTE Skins. Choose a skin from the css/skins
        folder instead of downloading all of them to reduce the load. -->
    <?php echo $this->Html->css('AdminLTE.skins/skin-'.(isset($theme['skin']) ? $theme['skin'] : 'blue').'.min'); ?>

    <?php echo $this->fetch('css'); ?>

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body class="hold-transition skin-<?php echo isset($theme['skin']) ? $theme['skin'] : 'blue'; ?> sidebar-mini">
<!-- Site wrapper -->

<div class="wrapper">
    <header class="main-header">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <a href="<?php echo $this->Url->build('/'); ?>" class="logo">
            <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
            <span class="logo-mini"> <?php echo ("HDS") ?> </span>
            <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
            <span class="logo-lg"> <?php echo ("HONOR<strong>DSystem</strong>") ?> </span>
        </a>
        <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
        <?php echo $this->element('nav-top') ?>
    </header>

    <!-- Left side column. contains the sidebar -->
    <?php echo $this->element('aside-main-sidebar'); ?>

    <!-- =============================================== -->

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">

        <?php echo $this->Flash->render(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Flash->render('auth'); ?>
        <?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>

    </div>
    <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

    <div class="footer" style="background-color: #222d32;" >
        <?php echo $this->element('footer'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->element('modalOpinions') ?>

    <!-- Control Sidebar -->
    <?php echo $this->element('aside-control-sidebar'); ?>

    <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
    <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
        immediately after the control sidebar -->
    <div class="control-sidebar-bg" style="  background-color: #222d32;"></div>
</div>



<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min'); ?>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./bootstrap/js/bootstrap'); ?>
<!-- SlimScroll -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min'); ?>
<!-- FastClick -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE./plugins/fastclick/fastclick'); ?>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<?php echo $this->Html->script('AdminLTE.AdminLTE.min'); ?>
<!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
<?php echo $this->fetch('script'); ?>

<?php echo $this->fetch('scriptBottom'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".navbar .menu").slimscroll({
            height: "200px",
            alwaysVisible: false,
            size: "3px"
        }).css("width", "100%");

        var a = $('a[href="<?php echo $this->request->webroot . $this->request->url ?>"]');
        if (!a.parent().hasClass('treeview')) {
            a.parent().addClass('active').parents('.treeview').addClass('active');
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect a different page, you can put in your controller right after the flash helper the redirection method, like this...

```
  public function delete($id = null)
{$this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
echo "Ok";
$department = $this->Departments->get($id);
if ($this->Departments->delete($department)) {
    $this->Flash->success(__('The department has been deleted.'));
    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'DIFFERENT PAGE']);
} else {
    $this->Flash->error(__('The department could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
}}
```

Else, if you want the redirect to take place to the same location you can use the redirect referer method...

```
return $this->redirect($this->referer());
```

Check more on the Cook book -> https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#redirecting-to-other-pages